# News Feed drop-down filter menu in Facebook iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

### The Problem

I am trying to replicate the *drop-down* style menu in the latest Facebook app.

At the top of the News Feed there is a "Most Recent" *row*:

[image: Facebook News Feed]

Tapping this *row* expands the view, pushing the News Feed (`UITableView`) down:

[image: Expanded News Feed Filter]

Tapping the down indicator will expand the menu fully.

### The Question

How is this menu implemented?

Given the behavior, I assume it is a custom view placed inside the `tableHeaderView`. But what custom view? A button, another tableview? What about the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do this as a table header. It'd need to be a section of the table that is initially 1 row and becomes multiple rows when you tap on it. Then all you would need to do to get an animation is to reload that section where animated=YES.

Comment: I see. Could you elaborate on the animation part?

Comment: ```-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:``` on UITableView will use whatever row animation you pick to add/remove rows. So initially the section would have 1 row, then you'd instead have 4 rows or so and use ```-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:``` to make the table animate in the new rows. Then once they pick one, do the same in reverse to go back.

Comment: `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` works, but, while more work,  `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` produced a smoother animation. Especially when a middle row was selected. Thanks for your help +100.